# A pre-existing hierarchial table as relational

Tags: ms-access, hierarchy

Currently the database contains something like so (these are the main fields but there's a large amount more):

```
+----------+----------------+----------+
| Agency   |     parent     | main_term
+----------+----------------+----------+
|        1 |  Office Staff  | Supplies |
|        1 |  Supplies      | Postings |
|        1 |  Supplies      | Artwork  |
+----------+----------------+----------+
```

The program would spit this data in a list like so, looking at the parent and main_term for proper indentation:

```
Agency #1:
Office Staff
--Supplies
----Postings
----Artwork
```

Right now the data seems redundant and creating a program for average users to edit or restructure the lists would turn out very confusing.

Is there a better way to structure this using multiple tables?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? This is quite easy with a recursive query.

Comment: Hey a_horse_with_no_name, I'm using Access.

Comment: No dice with MS-ACCESS, you will need to write a (VisualBasic) program for that.

Comment: I was looking more for guidance on restructuring the database. The way it's set up right now, would you say it was up to standard? Is there a way to make the data easier to manage?

Comment: If you have 50 items under supplies, are you really going to repeat `Supplies` 50 times in the table? Probably a lot more efficient to use surrogate keys for those instead of repeating the name so many times...